# MongoDB won't save url string

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to save an object in my Mongo database. The issue I face is that when I create the schema, it saves every single entry except the img url. I logged the url before creating the schema and it prints it successfully but when I create the schema object it doesn't get the value from the body.

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("URL:", req.body.img) //Logs the url successfully
    const pet = new Pet({
        name: req.body.name,
        petType: req.body.petType,
        breed: req.body.breed,
        age: req.body.age,
        img: req.body.img, //i can't get it here
        contact: req.body.contact,
        location: req.body.location,
        userp: req.body.contact,
    })
    console.log("This is a Pet");
    console.log(pet); //logs everything except the "img" field.

    try {
        const savedPet = await pet.save();
        console.log("This pet was saved", savedPet);
        res.json(savedPet); //returns an object without the "img" field
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }

});
```

Edit:
Here is my schema file as well:

````js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const petSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    petType: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    breed: {
        type: String,
        require: false
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        require: false
    },
    img: {
        data: String,
        require: false
    },
    contact: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },

    location: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },

    userp: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Pet', petSchema);```
````

Comment: What `console.log(typeof  req.body.img)` prints?

Comment: it's string type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. You use `data` instead `type` param specifically in this property.

```
img: {
  type: String,
  require: false
},
```